# Manually trying to take picture doesn't work

Tags: python, class, kivy

Basically I have this code:

```
import time

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MainWindow(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # Create a camera object

        self.cameraObject = Camera(play=False)

        self.cameraObject.play = True

        self.cameraObject.resolution = (300, 300)  # Specify the resolution


        # add camera and button to the layout

        layout.add_widget(self.cameraObject)

        # return the root widget

        return layout

    # Take the current frame of the video as the photo graph

    def onCameraClick(self, *args):
        self.cameraObject.export_to_png('hello.png')
        print("Success")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow().run()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        MainWindow().onCameraClick()
```

What it's supposed to do is:

1. Run the window
2. Show the webcam in window
3. Repeatedly take pictures using the webcam and save it as hello.png

What's it's doing:

1. Run the window
2. Show the webcam in window

What's wrong with my code? Is it something to do with trying to access a function inside another class? Or is it an argument error? If it is, I don't see any errors in the log messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to save the images after the `MainWindow().run()`, which does not return until the `App` is stopped. Try modifying your `build()` method to use `Clock.schedule_interval` to save the images:

```
def build(self):
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

    # Create a camera object

    self.cameraObject = Camera(play=False)

    self.cameraObject.play = True

    self.cameraObject.resolution = (300, 300)  # Specify the resolution


    # add camera and button to the layout

    layout.add_widget(self.cameraObject)
    
    # save some images
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.onCameraClick, 2)

    # return the root widget

    return layout
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the same window

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = MainWindow()
    win.run()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        win.onCameraClick()
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work, but I found out something, after I try close my tab, it starts to say "Success" meaning it started doing the while loop. This makes me think it is trying to start the while loop AFTER the window is closed, that's why it's not activating while the window is active.